# Multiple themes and landing pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-deployment, sitemesh, apache-tiles

I am working on a major dating site which will be developed using Spring MVC + Hibernate + (Apache Tiles or Sitemesh)

I want the website to have multiple themes and landing pages. Which would be more suitable for my needs Apache Tiles or Sitemesh? I would also appreciate any guides or tutorials on the best practice of having a multi theme website.

Comment: Stackoverflow has already a large number of "Tiles vs. Sitemash" questions. - Did none of them answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://tech.finn.no/2012/07/25/the-ultimate-view-tiles-3/) to see what can be done with tiles and dealing with multiple verticals or landing pages… should give you an idea of where tiles can take you at least.